# installing sock server 5 (ss5) on fedora 10

Tags: proxy

```
[root@jon1 ss5-3.7.8]# make
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/app/ss5-3.7.8/common'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/app/ss5-3.7.8/common'
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/app/ss5-3.7.8/modules'
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/app/ss5-3.7.8/modules/mod_socks4'
gcc -g -O2 -DLINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I . -I ../../include -shared -fPIC   -o mod_socks4.so SS5Mod_socks4.o ../../common/SS5OpenLdap.o -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: ../../common/SS5OpenLdap.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
../../common/SS5OpenLdap.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [mod_socks4.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/app/ss5-3.7.8/modules/mod_socks4'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/app/ss5-3.7.8/modules'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

in addition, any other socks5 server I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ss5 is in the fedora repos, is there a specific reason you're trying to compile it?

```
$ yum info ss5
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Available Packages
Name       : ss5
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 3.6.4
Release    : 3.fc10
Size       : 191 k
Repo       : updates
Summary    : Socks Server 5
URL        : http://sourceforge.net/projects/ss5
License    : GPLv2+
Description: ss5 is a socks server, which supports both SOCKS4 and SOCKS5
           : protocols, that runs on Linux/Solaris platforms.
```